# Update field if the ORDER BY is 1 descending?

Tags: php, sql-order-by, sql-update, str-replace

Is there a possible way to do this:

I want to update a field 'rank' according to the ORDER BY place.

For example: (pseudocode)

```
If id order by place = 1 then update rank field to place were id=get id


 rank place id

  1     1    5   PC
  2     2    8   MAC
```

is this possible?

Comment: May you rephrase your question, please?

Comment: ok. after I click a modify button I want the field rank in that table to update according to the place it has been given by the ORDER BY function. Lets say that id=9 order by "wins" -  is placed #10 in the table; well I want that #10 value to be added to the 'rank' field of that id in the same table....yes?.no?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE tbl_name
SET rank = 1
WHERE id = (
     SELECT id
     WHERE condition
     ORDER BY place DESC
     LIMIT 1
)
```

Or from your comment (I think MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE tbl_name
SET rank = 10
WHERE id = 9
ORDER BY wins DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You can always do a SELECT to check if these are the records you wish to UPDATE as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE id = (
     SELECT id
     WHERE condition
     ORDER BY place DESC
     LIMIT 1
)
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE id = 9
ORDER BY wins DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: the limit 1 indicates that it was placed 1st?

Comment: ORDER BY wins DESC LIMIT 1, returns only 1 record the last win

Answer (score 0):

Some RDBMS have a ROWNUM pseudocolumn in queries you can use for this.
You did not specify what database you are using, for example Oracle has this.

Comment: oh..i am using phpmyadmin mysql ..does it have it?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of mysql, but a qick google search turned up this simple rownum emulation trick: http://jimmod.com/blog/2008/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/   select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, p.* from player p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by score desc